# Allow mobile scrolling on accordion when li's open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this mobile menu and need to allow scrolling of the menu when the the li's are greater than the height of the window. I was close but if you open more than one li the scrolling breaks.

View in mobile...

https://www.sailpoint.com/

```
  $('#menu-wip-mobile').on('click', function(e){

//the li

      if($('.dropdown-toggle--submenu'.hasClass('show-submenu')){

// add scroll to mobile menu if li is open
      $('.navbar__menu__container ').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    } else{

// remove scroll
      $('.navbar__menu__container ').css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    }
    }
  })
```

Also need to disable body scrolling when the menu is open. This pretty much works when testing.

```
 $('.dropdown-toggle--main').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
  // disabling y scrolling when open
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('show')){
       $('body').css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    } else{
       $('body').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple approach to play with, you could try to set a maximum height to the LI that contains lot of items, and add inner scroll on this LI to allow user to scroll to last items.

Try:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
max-height: 50vh;
```

on your `.dropdown-submenu`.

Looks like this: look at the inner scrollbar in the LI

[image]

Comment: The for the response. Unfortunately still creates a 'bug' as if you were bold enough to open all the li's it would make navigating more difficult

Comment: cannot have it working in live, I don't see what you mean. I only tested it on your "Company" entry. So you have to adapt this depending on what is opened, maybe enable/disable the maximum height on particular items, etc...